# Heat equation on a disc : method of images?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, heat-equation, greens-function

Is it possible to obtain the Green function (fondamental solution) of the heat equation on the unit disc with Dirichlet boundary conditions **using the method of images**?

The equation is

\begin{aligned}
  &\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(t,x)-\Delta y(t,x) = 0  \qquad &t >0, \ x \in \mathbb{D},& \\
  &y(t,x)=0, \qquad &t >0, \ &x \in \mathbb{T}\\
 \end{aligned}

where $\mathbb{D}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 , \ |x| <1 \}$ is the open unit disc and $\mathbb{T}=\partial \mathbb{D}$ is the unit circle.

I want to use specifically this method in order to express the Green function of the disc using the Green function of the whole plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I specify that I can do it for Laplace equation (it is done for example in the book "Linear Partial
Differential Equations
for Scientists and Engineers" of Tyn Myint-U and
Lokenath Debnath at section 11.7), but in the case of the heat equation, the image point creates problems.